# How to calculate SUM base on 2 columns condition

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

[image]

How to calculate SUM base on 2 columns condition.
There is same product code but there is different specific "OPTION CODE."
So I would like to get "TOTAL SUM" base on two conditions by GROUP.

Please help me..

Comment: I think you are looking for case statement . or your question is not clear provide some  sample data and output ..

Answer (score 2):

```
Select sum(quantity) from 
your_table group by product_code, 
option_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Select 
  product_code, 
  option_code,
  sum(quantity) as total_sum
from 
  your_table 
group by 
  product_code, 
  option_code
```

Comment: This is actually the better answer. Gives you the exact output you wanted.